# When is the following integral zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functions

We assume we have two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $d$ some integer. I have the following integral expression
$$\forall b_{1},b_{2}  \leq d : \int_{-\delta}^{\delta}[ \int_0^t f(s)^{b_{1}}g(s)^{b_{2}} ds \cdot ( \int_0^t \sum_{i_{1},i_{2}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},i_{2}}{f(s')}^{i_{1}}{g(s')}^{i_{2}}ds')]dt=0$$

My question is the following, can I conclude that the only way this integral can become zero is by
$$ \sum_{i_{1},i_{2}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},i_{2}}{f(s')}^{i_{1}}{g(s')}^{i_{2}}=0$$
being zero already?

---

My attempts: What I already know is, that we can choose $g(s)^2f(s)^2$ which is a positive function. Using the mean-value theorem (these $f,g$ have nothing to do with the ones above)
$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x) g(x) d x=f(c) \int_{a}^{b} g(x) d x$$
we can conclude that the integral only can become zero if
$$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \int_0^t \sum_{i_{1},i_{2}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},i_{2}}{f(s')}^{i_{1}}{g(s')}^{i_{2}}ds'dt=0$$
is already zero, But here I am stuck.

Comment: There are three integrals but only two integration variables ($s$ and $t$)? Is it maybe a typo?

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the notation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By summing over $b_1, b_2$ and multiplying each term by $a_{b_1,b_2}$, and then using the linearity of the integrals, you can get that: $$\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \left(\int_0^t \sum_{i_{1},i_{2}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},i_{2}}{f(s')}^{i_{1}}{g(s')}^{i_{2}}ds'\right)^2 \mathrm{d}t = 0$$ and thus (I'll assume that $f$ and $g$ are continuous since you wanted to apply the mean value theorem) that, for all $t \in [-\delta, \delta]$ : $$\int_0^t \sum_{i_{1},i_{2}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},i_{2}}{f(s')}^{i_{1}}{g(s')}^{i_{2}}ds' = 0$$
By differentiating this expression, we do obtain, for all $t \in [-\delta,\delta]$ :
$$\sum_{i_{1},i_{2}=1}^{d}a_{i_{1},i_{2}}{f(t)}^{i_{1}}{g(t)}^{i_{2}} = 0$$